Stability criteria for any homogenous differential equation
It is well-known that for any linear homogenous differential system of the form:
$$\dot{x}(t) = A x(t)$$
for some constant matrix $A$, that if the real parts of the eigenvalues of $A$ are all negative then the system is stable, and if merely one has a positive real part then it is asymptotically unstable. So my simple question is, given any homogenous linear ordinary differential equation of the form
$$\sum_i M_i \frac{d^i}{dt^i}x(t) = 0$$
where $M_i$ are just the coefficients (matrices), then what is the stability criteria?
I would assume that something like "if the real parts of the eigenvalues of the coefficient matrices are all negative then the system is stable, and if merely one has a positive real part then it is asymptotically unstable." would be correct but missing a key property or aspect to simplify things. I want the criteria to be specifically in terms of the eigenvalues.

The second case can be rewritten as the first case. This can be done, assuming that in the summation the index $i$ goes from 1 till $n$ and that $M_n$ is invertible, using the following state vector $z(t)$ defined as
$$
z(t) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
x(t) \\
\frac{d}{dt} x(t) \\
\vdots \\
\frac{d^{n-1}}{dt^{n-1}} x(t)
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The dynamics of $z(t)$ can be written in the form
$$
\frac{d}{dt} z(t) = A\,z(t),
$$
with
$$
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & I & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & I \\
-M_n^{-1} M_1 & -M_n^{-1} M_2 & \cdots & -M_n^{-1} M_{n-2} & -M_n^{-1} M_{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
for which the stability can be evaluated using the eigenvalues of this matrix.
If $M_n$ is not invertible you are dealing with a system that needs to be described by a desciptor state space model. I am not familiar with the stability analysis of such systems, so I will leave this out of my answer.

Interesting. How does one find the eigenvalues of A here? I assume it's just $\det(A - \lambda I)$

You use an eigensolver or get extremely lucky with the structure of the various $M$s

Maybe worth adding that this is in the case where $M_n$ is invertible. When this is not the case, the situation will be quite different.

@KBS good point. I have updated my answer.

I can make another answer for the case where $M_n$ is singular but I need to find the courage and the time to do it. It will be a long answer....
